# how to read php cookies from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm going to keep this simple:
How can I read cookies that are not generated by asp.net from asp.net?
If I try to retrieve all the cookies using Request.Cookies, it only returns the ones that were generated by ASP.Net web pages, however, I need to retrieve ALL the cookies (i.e all the ones I see in my browser's cookie manager)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`Request.Cookies` should store all cookies making all available for viewing/editing (such as those created with PHP, javascript, etc.). So for all intents and purposes you're going about it the correct way.

However, one slip-up may be related to the context of the cookie:

- Is it global to the entire domain or just a sub-domain?
- Is it only for a specific path (which is also available for php?)
- Does it apply to one domain and the ASP site is on another domain?

All of those would alter which are available to ASP and the `Request.Cookies` accessor.

Comment: Well, when I open up my broweser's cookie manager, I see a whole bunch of cookies, but when I try to retrieve them using Request.Cookies, I just get one of them: ASP.NET_SessionId. That's why I'm looking for a way to get ALL those cookies.